# How to catch error thrown from an async function subscribed to an observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have the following simplified code:

```js
class LocationService {
  const location$: BehaviorSubject<Location> = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

  constructor() {
    location$.pipe(throttleTime(3000)).subscribe((location) => {
      this.trackNewLocation(location);
    });
  }

  private async trackNewLocation(location: Location): Promise<void> {...}

  public trackLocation(location: Location) {
    this.location$.next(location);
  }

}
```

Function `trackNewLocation` is an async function communicating with backend to save the new location to database. It can throw exception for instance when no connection.

Using rxjs is because I need to control the pace of location saving, e.g. every 3 seconds.

My question is when a client calling public function `trackLocation`, how can it try/catch the error thrown by the private function `trackNewLocation`?

Answer (score 0):

Since an async function returns a promise, you can refer to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) on how to catch an error.

As shown in the mozilla docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

```
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  throw 'Uh-oh!';
});

promise1.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

You would use the `.catch` function to catch an error